# Are there multiple ways of writing a thunk in SML?

Tags: sml, ml, thunk

Basic noob question:

I have data I need to evaluate lazily, the most common way of doing this is by making a `thunk`s; the way I'm used to do it is like this:

```
fun someFunc () = 
  let
    fun myThunk () = 2 + 2
  in
    (* body *)
  end
```

But every guide on Standard ML tells me that it's done like this:

```
fun someFunc () = 
  let
    val myThunk = fn () => 2 + 2
  in
    (* body *)
  end
```

So my questions are: Does it really matter? Isn't the output the same anyway? And what is the difference between making a function, and binding a lambda to a value anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no noticeable difference in your case. The `fun` keyword is syntactic sugar for `val rec`, which makes sure that you can reference the name that you are binding your function to in a recursive manner.

Thus

```
fun myThunk () = 2 + 2

val rec myThunk = fn () => 2 + 2

val myThunk = fn () => 2 + 2
```

will all yield the same result.